# I am trying to import a different product list from an array named clothingproducts

Tags: reactjs

I have three arrays one with all of the items and the other two with specific items. When I change the array name in context it works but when i create another context file with the same code (contextc) I get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined
 return value.products.map(product => {

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Product from "./Product";
import { ProductConsumer } from "../contextc";

export default class Productlist extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <header className="bg py-5 mb0 container-fluid clothing  border-bottom border-danger">
          <div className="container h-100">
            <div className="row h-100 align-items-center">
              <div className="col-lg-12">
                <h1 className="display-4 text-white mt-5 mb-2 text-center">
                  Clothing
                </h1>
                <p className="lead mb-5 text-white-50 text-center">
                  Our latest Releases.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>

        <div className="py-0    ">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <ProductConsumer>
                {value => {
                  return value.products.map(product => {
                    return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
                  });
                }}
              </ProductConsumer>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because value is undefined.

Comment: because value isn't defined anywhere in the component

Comment: Not Really i kind of understood it was undefined but was trying to figure out where to define it.